# Doubt over conjugation of verbs

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales

A veces cuando leo textos(Usualmente traducciones de novelas de otros idiomas)  encuentro la siguiente conjugación de verbos. Tomemos como ejemplo los verbos esparcir y parecer y la conjugación que no es usual, por lo menos en mi caso:

Esparcir --> esparciose
Parecer --> parecioles

Mi pregunta sería: ¿cuando es correcto usar esa conjugación?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Las conjugaciones son completamente normales.  Los verbos en sí que tienes en tus ejemplos son *esparció* y *pareció* (ambos en el pretérito perfecto simple del indicativo en tercera persona singular).

Lo que pasa es que aquí, los objetos átonos van en posposición (llamado «enclisis»), adjuntos al verbo.  Antes de la reforma de ortografía de 1999, estas palabras habrían sido escritas *esparcióse* y *parecióles*, pero ya que dicha reforma intentó deshacerse de las tildes superfluas, se las quitó en casos como estos porque al añadir *-se* o *-les* (por terminar en vocal, ene o ese) el acento natural recae en la penúltima sílaba, la cual es la que queremos acentuar.

En casos de una palabra llana, puede ser necesario tildar.  Con dos objetos, guardárase siempre :-)

- **compro**: lo compro *o* cómprolo
- **compro**: me lo compro *o* cómpromelo
- **compró**: lo compró *o* comprolo
- **compró**: se lo compró *o* compróselo

Hoy en día no es muy frecuente la enclisis con verbos personales (excepto en el imperativo afirmativo), no obstante, es una construcción plenamente válida.  Es más probable que lo veas si se cumple uno (o varios) de los siguientes casos:

- Dialecto regional por influencia de las lenguas gallega y asturiana
- Después de una pausa (y más si es el principio de una oración)
- Imperativo afirmativo (incluyendo exhortativo)
- Registro muy formal
- Lenguaje arcaico o áurico (o con toque arcaizante o dorante)

Recházase la enclisis en los siguientes casos:

- Dentro de una cláusula subordinada (*que se compró...* y nunca *que comprose...*)
- Negación (*no lo compro* y nunca *no cómprolo*)

Ten en cuenta también que en el caso de enclisis, prodúcense algunos cambios en las formas.  Si el verbo termina en *-s* y se le añade el pronombre *se*, se quita una de las eses aunque puede que ambas figuren en la pronunciación: *Tú cómpraselo a ellos*.  Si el verbo va en primera persona plural (terminando en *-amos*, *-emos* o *-imos*) y el primer pronombre que se le añade es *os*, o si es el subjuntivo exhortativo reflexivo en primera persona plural, quítase la *-s*: *comprámooslo*, *comprémonoslo*.

Aunque la enclisis yo la suelo usar, **no les puedo recomendar a hablantes no nativos que la usen**, en principio porque casi nadie la usa, porque las condiciones de su uso son, como podías ver, algo complicado, y porque su uso connota varias cosas al texto/habla que a lo mejor no querrían.  En mi caso, como asturfalante y aurisecularista, a nadie le sorprenderá que la use yo jaja, pero mi caso es algo especial jaja.

Comment: ¿Qué significa “aurisecularista”?

Comment: @aprendedor Una persona que estudia el Siglo de Oro (aurisecular es un adjetivo que significa «relativo o perteneciente al Siglo de Oro» de aura, u oro, y secula, o siglo)